# How to Perform Edit operation in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Controller**

```
class Demoexpe extends CI_Controller {
 public function index() {
        $data = array(
            'page_title' => 'Data',
            'page_name' => 'expendituretable/demoexpe_list',
        );
$data['display'] = $this->demoexpe_model->displaylist();
$this->load->view('admin/template', $data);
}

public function edit($id) {
  $data = array(
            'page_title' => 'Edit Expedata',
            'page_name' => 'expendituretable/demoexpe_edit'

        );
        $data['result']= $this->demoexpe_model->get_id($id);
         $this->load->view('admin/template', $data);
}
}
```

**Model**

```
 class Demoexpe_model extends CI_Model {
public function displaylist(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('expendituredata');
        $this->db->join('year','expendituredata.yearId = year.id');
          $this->db->join('speces','expendituredata.spacesId = speces.id');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }

    public function get_id($id){
         return $this->db->get_where('expendituredata', array('id' => $id))->row_array();
    }
}
```

**View**

Below page is edit page.

```
<?php echo form_open('Admin/Demoexpe/edit'); ?>
    <label>Data</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data" value="<?php echo $result['data']; ?>">
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

MY Question: I click Edit buttoon but can not display textfield value and can not update textfield value?

Answer (score 0):

In your get_id() function inside the model, you may also pass the column name of the table you're trying to access. The function below exactly returns the result from the database based from the parameter else it will return FALSE.

```
public function get_id($id,$column_name){
    return $this->db->get_where($column_name, array('id' => $id));
    $query = $this->db->get('expendituredata e');
    $row = $query->row();

    if ($row)
        return $row->{$column_name};

    return FALSE;
}
```

Then in your view you may directly access the returned data.

```
<?php echo form_open('Admin/Demoexpe/edit'); ?>
<label>Data</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data" value="<?php echo $result; ?>">
<?php echo form_close();?>
```